# route a custom url to a web-application

Tags: networking, network-programming

I have a Vista Home PC with computer-name say *office_pc1* and with IP say 192.168.11.40. I have a web-application, in that pc, which can be successfully accessed via the IP itself.

Now, my question is how can I access that web-application if I'm entering the url as: *http://support.somedomain.com/*, in my local intranet. Is that possible without using any Server OS? Can I implement, it by adding some entires in the **etc/hosts** file in the System32 folder of that machine.

(The web-application is a third-party application. so i cannot touch the source-code)

Is this a dreamy question?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fake it then you can add a entry to your hosts file yes. Add

```
192.168.11.40    support.somedomain.com
```

then run, at an elevated command prompt, ipconfig /flushdns

Now try pinging that FQDN and you should see it resolve to your 192 address and away you go

Comment: hi, ive already added an entry in the host file.
whenver i try to ping with FQDN, i'm getting an error reply as:
---
Ping request could not find host support.somedomain.com. Please check the name and try again.
---

I tried the same from that local machine and from the nearby pcs. but, getting the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you flush the DNS first? Did you make sure notepad didn't save the file as hosts.txt?

Comment: ah! thats a silly mistake. A small spelling-mistake. I eneterd 'supprt.somedomain.com' instead of 'support.somedomain.com'.
Now, i can successfully ping to 'support.somedomain.com' in the local machine.
 How can I ping from other pcs on the same network?

Comment: Add the same entry in every hosts file.

If you have an internal DNS server (which is unlikely for small offices or home) you could create a zone for that domain and add an A record to that zone, but now we're dipping into server fault territory.

Comment: You are right, we dont have any internal DNS server. instead of adding in every host file, is there any other workaround? Can i do anything on my proxy machine to acheive this?

Comment: Nope. You don't want it to reach the proxy. it's lots of manual updates for you!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.
I actually solved the problem is an alternate way.
As you know, adding a host entry in every pc is not an ideal solution.
By taking the risk, I added the entry into my proxy machines hosts file. And *Chanrmingly*, its working.

Hope this helps.
Thanks.